# Array Sorting greater number of data to less number of data

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**Result:** it works fine in April and May (displaying data and sort is working) but when coming to June and July it displays data but unable to sort. I realise total number of data in

April is 4 - Working

May is 4 - Working

June is 3 - Not Working

July is 2 - Not Working

then i have done monthly calculation from july to April, it works fine. but i want to do it from April to July. Please help how can i sort data if an array where data for every month is changing contuinusly.

**salarymonthwise**

```
04-2016
05-2016
06-2016
07-2016
```

**details**

```
101 2.3 04-2016
102 2.1 04-2016
103 1.6 04-2016
104 5.3 04-2016
101 2.1 05-2016
102 3.6 05-2016
103 6.5 05-2016
104 9.6 05-2016
101 6.1 06-2016
102 8.6 06-2016
103 5.5 06-2016
101 6.1 07-2016
102 8.6 07-2016

$query = "select * from salarymonthwise;";
$res = mysql_query($query, $dblink);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    $query1 = "select * from details where month='$row[2]';";
    $res1 = mysql_query($query1, $dblink);
    $numrow = mysql_num_row($res1);
    $i = 0;
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($res1)) {
        $array[$i]['id'] = $row1[0]; //id
        $array[$i]['value'] = $row1[1]; //id
$i++

    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $rowdata) {
        $edition[$key] = $rowdata['value'];
    }
    array_multisort($edition, SORT_DESC, $array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numrow; $i++) {
        echo $array[$i]['id'] . " - " . $array[$i]['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea what `$row['roi']` is

Comment: By the way, if you do `$array[0]['id']=101;` and then `$array[0]['id']=104;` you're just overwriting the previous entry at `$array[0]['id']`

Comment: Please check . I modified..

Comment: If this is the exact code which is not working then you need to add an `$array = [];` at the beginning of the loop (`while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) { $array = []; ...` . This explains why it works when you go from july to april (because July has 2 elements and april overwrites them).

Comment: thanks Sorting is working on values now but there is some duplicate id . while print array.

Comment: Try doing the same to `$edition` i.e. `$edition = [];` at the start of the loop

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Its done .. it was matter of these two only. Thanks a lot. You are really a genius... thanks

Comment: Can you please explain me the use of this in my case... I didnot understand.

Comment: You're updating arrays for each loop, however you're not working on clean arrays for each month so you end up with data from the previous month written in the arrays. It works if the next month has more data because all the previous contents will be overwritten, however it will break if you write 4 entries for 1 month and then overwrite the first 2 entries for the next month.